# Select query from multiple tables and multiple likes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to query several tables with just one query string with no luck. I've read maybe 50 posts in here with no avail. Here's what I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE (id LIKE :searchterm
    OR fname LIKE :searchterm
    OR lname LIKE :searchterm)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE (id LIKE :searchterm
    OR lang1 LIKE :searchterm
    OR lang2 LIKE :searchterm)
    ";
try
{
    $core = Core::getInstance();
    $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':searchterm', $this->_searchTerm);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
            print_r($result);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't get result.";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If I remove from the UNION ALL and leave just the first SELECT, it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that tables have same length? Can you print error info after `$stmnt->execute();` using `print_r($stmnt->errorInfo())`?

Comment: You should avoid using `SELECT * ...` and specify the columns explicitly

Comment: No, they don't. Can I still SELECT * from them? Or do I need to specify all the fields for each table? Hoping not.

Comment: You can't use UNION when they have a different number of fields. But if you specify the same number of fields (say 3) in both `select` clauses then you can.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to use a query to fetch the table(s) and id(s) matching the sear and use one or more queries to fetch those results. Thanks ;)